# Track another device without Internet connection

Tags: android, gps, tracker

I'm working on a personal app and I want to know if it's possible to track another device without any Internet connection. For example, track a friend's device. My idea is to have two apps, one on my device and the other on my friend's device. I know how to do that with internet connection (the phone that I want to track sends it's location to a server and the phone tracking get the location by, for example, a rest service and display it on map). But there is a way to do it without the server side? I don't want to depend on internet. Thanks.

Comment: Use message to send location of other device.

Comment: Get any sms packages there are so many sites which provides you sms packages with library integration you can use that to send message to other device to track it

Comment: That would solve my problem! Thanks! Please, put in like an answer so I can accept.

Comment: Hey added as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get any `sms` packages there are so many sites which provides you `sms` packages with `library integration` you can use that to send message to other device to track it. And then when you sending messages from one device to other device then put some unique code so you can identify your message to other device when received.

Comment: I know it´s an older post, but for an sms tracking, I guess there must be some credit on your sim card or you must have a contract about free sms, because sms are not for free. Am I correct?

Comment: For Sms to send we need atleast a Sms package or some sort of credits to send, without that we can't send Sms.

Comment: Its my pleasure @Opiatefuchs. I was just suggesting what you can use.

Answer (score 1):

Most ways of getting a connection will involve a net connection. There are other ways but they have their limitations, e.g via bluetooth (limited by distance unless you had an impressive mesh network that you could rely on). Phone companies can use triangulation but you won't have access to this information.

two-way BLE beacons would also be a potential but again, you would need a substantial network of these to track the device for you.

If your question is can you track a device via GPS external to the device, then in real terms, no.

An addition to my answer. If by internet you mean that you don't want to host a server then, there are limited ways to get around this, but they still rely on an internet connection.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I like the sms solution.